# Require Client SSL - keeping the session alive

Tags: ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate, authentication, certificate

i have a PIV enabled website that basically requires all PIV card certificates to match the server store, upon login, by requiring client certificate on the IIS. as soon as the card is removed from the reader, the session gets lost and the user gets the dreaded 403 error. has anyone come across this? is it possible to somehow cache or keep the client certificate handshake alive, after the PIV card is removed?